# Manually bind form data in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have a web api with some actions that should receive both data and files. To do so, I am accepting multipart/form-data instead of JSON and binding to the model using `[FromForm]`:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "MyCustomPolicy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]MyCustomDto myDto)
{
    // Do some stuff here
}

public class MyCustomDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine and is correctly bound to the DTO.
The Policy is checked and enforced using a AuthorizationHandler, which also works fine.
In said AuthorizationHandler, I need to access some stuff passed to the controller, such as IDs in the route or DTOs.
Accessing route data is quite easy with `authContext.RouteData.Values["nameOfIdField"]`.
For the body, however, I have created a helper extension method that reads the body stream and deserializes it:

```cs
public static async Task<T> DeserializeBody<T>(this AuthorizationFilterContext context, string name)
{
    var content = string.Empty;

    using(var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
}
```

Again, this also works quite fine. However, now I am having trouble with DTOs that are not passed as JSON but - as said in the beginning - as form data.
The body's content is not a JSON that can be serialized easily:

```
-----------------------------7e2b13b820d4a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

232  
-----------------------------7e2b13b820d4a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

test  
-----------------------------7e2b13b820d4a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"; filename="C:\Temp\Test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Is there any way to bind this to my DTO easily, without having to manually parse it?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to do authorization based on message data, *after* the data is parsed and created for you?

Comment: @nvoigt do you have any link or resource on that? Because when I looked up how to do authorization, the solution on top (kind of) was what I found, and no other way.

Comment: I don't have any references, but it seems to be common sense... parsing all your different messages in your middleware and knowing their semantic meaning  would be a huge ball of mud. Only the actual controller can know whether the ItemId you got passed needs to be checked for read access or write access, because it depends on what it will do with it.

Comment: For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: In addition, replicating all your logic for data transfer in your authorization method means you have all of that as a big redundancy. You cannot just swap a `[FromQuery]` and a `[FromRoute]` because while it seems easy enough, you have replicated that logic somewhere hidden from sight and it will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off handling this situation in your action method:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    public SomeController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]MyCustomDto myDto)
    {
        var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, myDto, "MyCustomPolicy");
        if (!authorizationResult.Succeeded)
            return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? Forbid() : (IActionResult)Challenge();

        // Do some stuff here
    }
```

And you define your authorization handler like this:

```
public class MyCustomDtoAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyCustomDtoRequirement, MyCustomDto>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyCustomDtoRequirement requirement, MyCustomDto resource)
    {
        // your authorization logic based on the resource argument...
    }
}
```

The big problem with choosing the *AuthorizeFilter* way is that authorization filters are executed **before** model binding takes place. (Just take a look at the source of the [ResourceInvoker](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d46948da1d4709bcb8ae0094074a307ece636b4d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ResourceInvoker.cs#L147) class.) You would need to bind your model manually to access the required information for authorization in it. Then the framework would do its job resulting in model binding being done two times and thus, in performance degradation. And this should and could be avoided as it was described earlier.

**Update**

I've just noticed I accidentally left an important piece of code out of the action method. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

> In said AuthorizationHandler, I need to access some stuff passed to the controller, such as IDs in the route or DTOs

Please don't do that. You are basically replicating the logic already in place on how to parse your parameters from the request.

The basic handlers are for basic cases: For example, only authenticated members of the "BookClub" role should be able to access the `BooksController` methods. That's great.

As soon as you find yourself needing information from the message itself, please don't go and do all of that parsing by hand. Let ASP do it's thing and parse the message as per your given constraints *and then* when the message is complete, invoke your authorization logic on the objects you got.

[Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)